# how to Extract hostname from url using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, url

Here is the sample of URLs.

```
1) domain.com/our-work/insights/tips-and-advice/2008/02/04/the-path-to-good-design-is-proper-analytics
2) subdomain.domain.com
3) im.domain.com/About.htm
4) domain.uk/help.htm
```

Get the Result like this

```
domain.com
domain.uk
```

Comment: I think it can be done quite simply using [regex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp). Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you can simply use the [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method with `/` as delimiter to extract the hostname and then you take the end of the hostname (that contains a dot) with [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```
var m = url.split('/')[0].match(/[^.]+\.[^.]+$/);
if (m)
    var domain = m[0];
```

Note: if the url begins with a scheme you need to remove it before:

```
var pat = '^https?://';
url = url.replace(new RegExp(pat, 'i'), '');
```

---

An other way consists to find the domain directly:

```
var pat = '^(?:https?://)?(?:[^/:]*:[^/@]*@)?[^/]*([^./]+\\.[^./]+)';
var m = url.match(new RegExp(pat, 'i'));
if (m)
    var domain = m[1];
```

But in this case, you need to deal with a possible login/pass part before the hostname. This is the reason of this subpattern: `(?:[^/:]*:[^/@]*@)?`

Comment: it doesn't gives the expected result.

Comment: @Musakkhir: exact, I have readen the question too quickly! Is there always only one dot in the domain name?

Comment: There will be always one dot in domain name, above pattern is not working for those urls.

Answer (score 0):

You can get host name by

```
window.location.hostname
```

**[Manual](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hostname.asp)**

Comment: The OP wants to get the hostname of the url strings, not the page's url. Vivek's solution is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think this regex (*if you want to do with the regex*) will do the job:

```
\w+\.(?=(com|uk))
```

### demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/bP1iA7/1).

Answer (score 0):

try this.

you can achieve this functionality by javascript function.

```
var name = document.domain;
```

and you want to find out the domain name from sub-domain than use this.

```
var parts = location.hostname.split('.');
var subdomain = parts.shift();
var upperleveldomain = parts.join('.');
var sndleveldomain = parts.slice(-2).join('.');
alert(sndleveldomain);
```

Comment: The above urls are in string.

Comment: so in which datatype you want?

Comment: The location.hostname works with only current domain. I want the expected results from all urls which is in string form.

Comment: so what the problem u  faced in this ans?